# Sum columns row-wise with similar names

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, rowwise

I have a *dataframe* that has lots of columns that are something like this:

```
data <- data.frame (a.1 = 1:5, a.2b = 3:7, a.5 = 5:9, bt.16 = 4:8, bt.12342 = 7:11)
```

I'd like a result with columns that sum the variables that have the same prefix. In this example, I want to return a dataframe:
a = (9:13), bt = (11:15)

My real data set is quite a bit more complicated (I want to combine page view counts for web pages with different utm parameters) but a solution for this case should put me on the right track.

Comment: What do you mean by "variables that have the same prefix"?

Comment: Does this work? `library(magrittr);
lapply(c("a","bt"), function(x) rowSums(data[, grepl(x, names(data))])) %>% setNames(., c("a","bt")) %>% data.frame`

Comment: have you tried something like `select(data, starts_with("prefix"))` from `tidyverse` functions?

Comment: To add to Mike's answer, you may want `startsWith(names(data), x)]` instead of `grepl(x, names(data))`

Answer (score 7):

Here a solution with base R:

```
> prefixes = unique(sub("\\..*", "", colnames(data)))
> sapply(prefixes, function(x)rowSums(data[,startsWith(colnames(data), x)]))
      a bt
[1,]  9 11
[2,] 12 13
[3,] 15 15
[4,] 18 17
[5,] 21 19
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```r
library(tidyverse)
data.frame (a.1 = 1:5, a.2b = 3:7, a.5 = 5:9, bt.16 = 4:8, bt.12342 = 7:11) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(k, v, -rowname) %>% 
  separate(k, letters[1:2]) %>% 
  group_by(rowname, a) %>% 
  summarise(Sum=sum(v)) %>% 
  spread(a, Sum)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   rowname [5]
#>   rowname     a    bt
#>   <chr>   <int> <int>
#> 1 1           9    11
#> 2 2          12    13
#> 3 3          15    15
#> 4 4          18    17
#> 5 5          21    19
```

Created on 2018-04-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

You can also do:

```r
data.frame (a.1 = 1:5, a.2b = 3:7, a.5 = 5:9, bt.16 = 4:8, bt.12342 = 7:11) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = c(".value", "set"), names_sep = "[.]") %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  summarise(across(a:bt,sum, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  rowname     a    bt
  <chr>   <int> <int>
1 1           9    11
2 2          12    13
3 3          15    15
4 4          18    17
5 5          21    19
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

t(data) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  group_by(., id = gsub('\\..*', '', rownames(.))) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = 'id') %>%
  t()
```

**Result:**

```
    a bt
X1  9 11
X2 12 13
X3 15 15
X4 18 17
X5 21 19
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data <- data.frame (a.1 = 1:5, a.2b = 3:7, a.5 = 5:9, bt.16 = 4:8, bt.12342 = 7:11)
i <- grepl("a.", names(data), fixed = TRUE)
result <- data.frame(a=rowSums(data[, i]), bt=rowSums(data[, !i]))
result
# > result
#    a bt
# 1  9 11
# 2 12 13
# 3 15 15
# 4 18 17
# 5 21 19
```

If you have more than two prefixes you can do something like:

```
prefs <- c("a.", "bt.")
as.data.frame(lapply(prefs, function(p) rowSums(data[, grepl(p, names(data), fixed = TRUE)]) ))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a one-liner approach using base R's `rowsum` function:

```
> t(rowsum(t(data), group = sub("\\..*", "", colnames(data))))
      a bt
[1,]  9 11
[2,] 12 13
[3,] 15 15
[4,] 18 17
[5,] 21 19
```

The idea is to transpose the data so that the columns become rows, then apply the `rowsum` function to sum up these rows indexed by the same group label. Transposing again returns the data to its original form, now with the columns with the same labels summed up.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use matrix product:

```
data <- data.frame (a.1 = 1:5, a.2b = 3:7, a.5 = 5:9, bt.16 = 4:8, bt.12342 = 7:11)
as.matrix(data) %*% sapply(c("a","bt"), function(a,b){startsWith(b,a)}, colnames(data))
```

Result:

```
      a bt
[1,]  9 11
[2,] 12 13
[3,] 15 15
[4,] 18 17
[5,] 21 19
```

Here `sapply(c("a","bt"), function(a,b){startsWith(b,a)}, colnames(data))` is

```
         a    bt
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE
```

denoting how the columns should be combined. Note that in this way you can easily keep the row names of your data.

Here `sapply` is used to keep column names, otherwise you can simply use `outer(colnames(data), c("a","bt"), startsWith)` and then set column names by yourself.